# How can I change the color of a label in css?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to style a selection button such that if a user clicks on it, the background color and the text color changes to show that it has been selected. 
I am able to change the background color of the button, however, the color of the text remains the same.
This is the button before clicking:
[image: Before clicking]

After Clicking:
[image: After clicking]

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+label:after {
  transform: scale(4.2);
}

.braids {
  outline: none;
  user-select: none;
  color: #673AB7;
  font-size: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.04rem;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  border: 0.2rem solid #673AB7;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 #673AB7;
}

.braids::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
  background-color: #673AB7;
  color: white;
}

.braids:active {
  top: 3px;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" /><label class="braids" for="cb1">Braids</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following css:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked+label {
  background-color: #673AB7;
  color: white;
}
```

Note: I have commented out the scale transform.

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+label {
  background-color: #673AB7;
  color: white;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+label:after {
  /*transform: scale(4.2);*/
}

.braids {
  outline: none;
  user-select: none;
  color: #673AB7;
  font-size: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.04rem;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  border: 0.2rem solid #673AB7;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 #673AB7;
}

.braids::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
  background-color: #673AB7;
  color: white;
}

.braids:active {
  top: 3px;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" /><label class="braids" for="cb1">Braids</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using your current CSS style, the .braids::after will be on top of the label element, which hides the text from your label element.

To make it work, add "Braids" to the content property. For example:

```
.braids::after {
    content: "Braids";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
    background-color:  #673AB7;
    color: white;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'll test it out